# Launch installed air application from browser for register file type

Tags: air, flash-builder

I have an air application register for a special filetype .part. After manual installation If I double click on a .part file it opened our air application and invoke the events perfectly. But if I am downloading the same file type from browser it doesn't show our air application as a default application to open with.

I also have this code in the descriptor file

```
<allowBrowserInvocation>true</allowBrowserInvocation>;
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

--

Fixed that. The problem was the extension of file I was using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed that. The problem was the extension of file I was using.